# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, match

I'm trying to put a group of datas in my list thanks to this code but the info_hash have some problems:

```
handshake = piece_request_handshake.findall(hex_data)
            match = piece_request_handshake.match(hex_data)
            info_hash = match.group('info_hash')

            # If the packet is a packet type handshake, if the dest and src ip are not in the list "liste" and if the handshake is not empty, then we add the adress src and dest to the list
            if handshake and (src_ip+" "+dst_ip+" "+info_hash) not in liste and (dst_ip+" "+src_ip+" "+info_hash) not in liste and handshake != '':
                liste.append(src_ip+" "+dst_ip+" "+info_hash)
```

But i don't know why it returns me this error:

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Documents/mysite/polls# python scriptbdd.py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "scriptbdd.py", line 134, in run
    self.p.dispatch(0, PieceRequestSniffer.cb)
  File "scriptbdd.py", line 80, in cb
    info_hash = match.group('info_hash')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I don't really understand how can i solve it after many try i ask for your help.

Comment: `piece_request_handshake.match(hex_data)` is returning `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of that your regex engine doesn't found a match so it returns `None` and you tried to get its `group`. For get ride of that you can use a `try-except` :

```
handshake = piece_request_handshake.findall(hex_data)
            match = piece_request_handshake.match(hex_data)
            try :
              info_hash = match.group('info_hash')
              # If the packet is a packet type handshake, if the dest and src ip are not in the list "liste" and if the handshake is not empty, then we add the adress src and dest to the list
              if info_hash and handshake and (src_ip+" "+dst_ip+" "+info_hash) not in liste and (dst_ip+" "+src_ip+" "+info_hash) not in liste and handshake != '':
                liste.append(src_ip+" "+dst_ip+" "+info_hash)
            except AttributeError:
                 print 'there is no match'
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my level, now it raise this error:
`Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "scriptbdd.py", line 137, in run
    self.p.dispatch(0, PieceRequestSniffer.cb)
  File "scriptbdd.py", line 117, in cb
    if element == (src_ip2+" "+dst_ip2+" "+info_hash) or element == (dst_ip2+" "+src_ip2+" "+info_hash):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'info_hash' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @Kastra : Oh well done good idea,I don't understand why the problem remains:

`Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "scriptbdd.py", line 137, in run
    self.p.dispatch(0, PieceRequestSniffer.cb)
  File "scriptbdd.py", line 86, in cb
    if info_hash and handshake and (src_ip+" "+dst_ip+" "+info_hash) not in liste and (dst_ip+" "+src_ip+" "+info_hash) not in liste and handshake != '':
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'info_hash' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @Bouh10 Ah you need to put the rest of your code within `try`. check the edit

Answer (score 1):

[It's quite obvious](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) : `re.match()` returns `None` if the expression didn't match the string, and `None` has no attribute `group`. IOW you have to check the return of `re.match()` before doing anything with it:

```
match = piece_request_handshake.match(hex_data)
if match is not None:
    info_hash = match.group('info_hash')
    # etc
else:
    # do whatever else
    print "didn't match"
```

Comment: If it were obvious to them they wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @PeterWood it's obvious from the doc : "If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern" https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

Comment: I don't think it's to do with documentation. It's more understanding what the exception meant, and that `match` was `None`.